# Is this the appropriate way to detect the "Enter" key in a input "type=text" field for all (or at least most) browsers?

Tags: javascript, properties, enter, onkeypress

The snippet below shows the way I've coded an `onKeyPress` function to call a function when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. Will this handle all (or at least most) browsers?

```js
function saveMarginKeyPress(thisArg, theEvent) {
    // If property is present, call the saveButton onClick function and then exit
    if ((theEvent.keyCode) && (theEvent.keycode == 13)) { saveMarginClicked(); return; }
    if ((theEvent.charCode) && (theEvent.charCode == 13)) { saveMarginClicked(); return; }
    if ((theEvent.which) && (theEvent.which == 13)) { saveMarginClicked(); return; }
}

function saveMarginClicked() { 
    alert("You pressed the Enter key");
}
```

```html
<input id="marginTopText" onkeypress="saveMarginKeyPress(this, event)" name="marginTop" type="text" style="width: 28px" />
```

You might find my long names a bit overdone, I simply prefer to fully identify functions and fields with appropriate names.

Comment: watch your case `theEvent.keyCode` != `theEvent.keycode`; so no, this wont work in any browser supporting e.keyCode... ;)

Comment: Consider: `var key = evt.keyCode || evt.charCode || evt.which; if (key == 13)...`. Seems to fail in older IE.

Comment: I see now that I have keyCode as "keyCode" and then "keycode" on the same line, no less. Thanks, good  eyeballing - should I stick to lower case or, just be a little paranoid, aned check for all six possibilities - 3 each of upper and lower case? I guess I squeezed by with the browsers I tested with as regards my case inconsistency.

Comment: Opps - I guess there is no case to worry about for "which."

Comment: A better sequence that accommodates IE 8 and lower better seems to be: `var key = evt.charCode || evt.which || evt.keyCode`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `keydown` or `keyup` event, and check the `keyCode` property.  IE 5-7 did not trigger the `keypress` event for the enter key.

```js
function saveMarginKeyPress(thisArg, theEvent) {
    // If property is present, call the saveButton onClick function and then exit
    if (theEvent.keyCode == 13) {
        saveMarginClicked();
    }
}

function saveMarginClicked() { 
    alert("You pressed the Enter key");
}
```

```html
<input id="marginTopText" onkeydown="saveMarginKeyPress(this, event)" name="marginTop" type="text" style="width: 28px" />
```

The above is sufficient for all browsers today, and mostly likely for at least the next several years.  However, you should be aware that there's finally a [standard for keyboard events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-KeyboardEvent).  Unfortunately, it's only implemented in IE and FireFox so far, but not yet in Chrome, Safari, and Opera.  It would be a good habit to plan for the future by checking the `key` property first, before falling back to the legacy `keyCode` property:

```js
function saveMarginKeyPress(thisArg, theEvent) {
    // If property is present, call the saveButton onClick function and then exit
    if (theEvent.key == "Enter" || theEvent.keyCode == 13) {
        saveMarginClicked();
    }
}

function saveMarginClicked() { 
    alert("You pressed the Enter key");
}
```

```html
<input id="marginTopText" onkeydown="saveMarginKeyPress(this, event)" name="marginTop" type="text" style="width: 28px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `theEvent` may not be treated well in some browsers, so try something like that

```
onkeydown="var Key = (event) ? event.keyCode : e.which; if(Key==13)...
```